# Dovecot Authentication failed if trying login with @domain

Tags: centos, authentication, dovecot, imap, roundcube

When I try to test my IMAP server functionality using telnet I encounter the following error.

If during the test i omit the @domain.ex everything works fine(as you can see below);

```
a login user password
a OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT 
SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL 
CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC 
ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS SPECIAL-USE BINARY MOVE] Logged in
```

if I try using username@domain.ex . I receive the following error:

```
a login user@domain.ex password
a NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

Someone knows where i'm mistaking ?

The output of `dovecot -n`

```
# 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)  
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = postfix
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb { 
  driver = passwd
}
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `dovecot -n` in above question?

Comment: with pleasure...http://pastebin.com/GgBvs98g

Comment: Umm... did you truncate the output? The `userdb` section looks empty.

Comment: sorry, my fault :
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}

Answer (score 0):

For authentication driver, you have selected `passwd` driver. In other words, user will be looked in `/etc/passwd` file. [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/) the content of `/etc/passwd` looks like.

Usually `/etc/passwd` was contain username only and lacks of domain part. So, it's obvious why it fails. Here [some resources](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/Passwd) regarding dovecot with passwd auth.

Comment: Instead of `Here some resources regarding dovecot with passwd auth.` please suggest a solution in your answer